# Optimal way to create multiple property relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create multiple Users nodes in a single query. They are also linked with a friend relation in the same query. When I profile the query I see that for each property I set to a relation a db call is made. This is making the query expensive when there are many relations and properties of each relation. How can I reduce the cost for this query?

The query is the following:

```
PROFILE  MERGE (user: User {myId: "1"}) WITH user 
UNWIND [
{myId: "2",userLastName: "2",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "3",userLastName: "3",userAddressId: "3",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "4",userLastName: "4",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "5",userLastName: "5",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "6",userLastName: "6",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "7",userLastName: "7",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "8",userLastName: "8",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0},
{myId: "9",userLastName: "9",userAddressId: "1",hasImage: false,randomId: 0} 
] as row  
MERGE (friend: User {myId: row.myId})  ON CREATE SET friend.name = row.userLastName   
MERGE (user)-[c:KNOWS]->(friend)  ON CREATE SET c = row
```

[As you can see in this profile result image there are over 88 db calls in just creating the relation properties from map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qW1e.png)

How can I avoid so many db calls for this query?

Note: `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.myId IS UNIQUE` is already set on the db.

Edit:

After following the instructions from @ChristopheWillemsen as explained in  [this video](https://dzone.com/articles/cypher-write-fast-and-furious), The execution time on my machine dropped from 500+ms to ~40ms for 100 to 500 records.

Answer (score 0):

You ask the DB to create some properties on the relationship, so it's normal to have some DB hits.

If you want to reduce a little the work of the DB, you can explicit all the SET you want to do on `ON CREATE SET c = row` like this :

```
MERGE (user)-[c:KNOWS]->(friend)  
 ON CREATE SET c.myId = row.myId,
               c.userLastName=row.userLastName,
               c.userAddressId=row.userAddressId,
               c.hasImage=row.hasImage,
               c.randomId=row.randomId
```

Comment: You are right. It seem to bring down little load. Do you suggest any better way to create these nodes and relations? This one is taking too much of time if there are 1000s of records.

Comment: Use parameters everywhere, for only 1000 records it should take less than 500ms. Check my video on your exact use case here https://dzone.com/articles/cypher-write-fast-and-furious

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen Thanks for the suggestion. Right now for 1000 records, it takes a couple of seconds. Let me see how using parameters will help. Will post the results once done. However, I see people being able to achieve way more No of writes while benchmarking. 500ms still seems large. Is it because of the way the data is modeled here?

Comment: A `merge` is less faster than a `create`, so if you can change them, you will see a real difference.  For example it can be better to create all the users and then the `KNOWS` edges. Using parameterized query will help a lot if you run multiple times the same query. Moreover, Neo4j's configuration (heap + pagecache) and your material specification are also important.

Comment: @PradeepReddy if you look at the video, you will see that I write 27k objects in less than a second, I gave 500ms as a treshold.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. After parameterizing the same query, The execution time on my machine dropped from 500+ms to ~40ms for 100 to 500 records. How can I promote @ChristopheWillemsen's comment as the answer, as it solved my issue and doubts?

Comment: @PradeepReddy no need, just edit your question with the solution and point to the video if you want ;-)